# Why I can't inject multiple instances of a bean?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, dependency-injection, javabeans

I have two beans: one manage a single stock, other manage the movements between two stocks. So, in the MovStock bean I have:

```
@EJB
private Stock stock1;
@EJB
private Stock stock2;

[...]

public void setStocks(int idStock1, int idStock2) {
  stock1.loadStock(idStock1);
  stock2.loadStock(idStock2);
}
```

somewhere in my code, on another bean, I do:

```
@EJB
private MovStock movStock;

[...]

movStock.setStocks(10,20);
```

but it result in stock1 and stock2 to hold the same stock (20). Surely I'm doing something wrong, but what's the correct way to use multiple instance of the same bean that use @PersistenceContext, etc?

thank you

Comment: Probably because the injected instance is the same for both `Stock`, you need some kind of qualifier to inject two different instances

Comment: yes, but what qualifier? I'm stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beans are container managed. So you don't have to worry about instances. Container will create new ones, when needed, but it will have this same state (if Statefull). It looks like `Stock` shouldn't be Enterprise Bean, but DTO. You shouldn't perform data operations on EJB's. EJB's should perform it on appropriate structures (DTO).

Comment: mmm, maybe I wat not clear in my question. Stock is a bean that hold the logic for managing a stock (ie: add, sub), and MovStock is a bean that hold the logic for managing movements (move 10 from stock1 to stock2), so in MovStock I need to use the Stock beans (a movement use the Movement entity, a jpa table, and two stocks, for add and sub quantities individually).

Comment: For performing operations on Entities we use Dao's (Data access objects.) Dao can be EJB. But for holding data you should create DTO's. That DTO's aren't container managed, so you can have multiple independed instances of it. `Stock is a bean that hold the logic for managing a stock` - that's right, but Stock shouldn't contain stock.  This should be different object, and not EJB.

Comment: so, if I understand, I need a two beans (the stock and movstock logic), two entities (that are bind to the stock and movstock table) and various DTOs, and in Stock bean I cannot use, for example, this.idStock, but I have to manage two DTOs in my MovStock and pass it to the Stock bean? So it's impossibile to have a Stock that hold the logic and "current" stock?

Comment: It's hard to say, because i don't know why you want to hold "current" stock, but yes. Unless you want "current" stock not being shared... But generally, "current" stock dto should be contained in runtime method (that one which invokes logic methods on stocks)

Comment: Maybe it's "old style" but I like to do:
`Stock s = new Stock()
s.load(1);
s.add(5);
s.save();`
so I'm trying to put logic and some data in the same object, but I think this is not the point using beans.